# How do I set the delegate for a text field in the interface builder to "files owner"?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I am trying to implement the :

```
- (BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
```

method. For some reason it is not being called. I have set the text field to first responder in the code. I understand I also need to set the delegate for the text field in interface builder to 'files owner'. How do that? Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can right click drag from the text field on the interface builder canvas to the `File's Owner` icon in the object list on the left.

Or you can select the text field, open the outlet inspector, drag from the little circle next to `delegate` over to the `File's Owner` icon in the object list.

Or you can right click drag from the text field icon in the object list to the same `File's Owner` icon in that list.

Or you can set the delegate in code.

Answer (score 17):

If you have declared your `UITextField` as an `IBOutlet` property, you can just add the following line in your `viewDidLoad`: `self.myTextField.delegate = self`

Alternatively, you can do it in Storyboards.

[image]